# New SharePoint web applications Ports shows 80 even different application created on different port with hostname?

Tags: 2013, 2010, iis, port

I created new web application with HostName and Port using C.A

but in `C.A>Manage web applications >` always Port showing 80 even I given different port when I created a new web application.

Here I have to create many web applications with different ports and hostnames

My questions are:

1. why that behaviour in SharePoint it shows only port 80 in managed web applications and IIS bindings shows hostname in IIS for SharePoint web application.
2. How users request and IIS response works in this case?

If users access web applications which are on different ports ,is all users request came to web front end servers on port 80 ? or users traffic  goes to a specific port that web application created?

we are using the load balancer to route users request to SharePoint web front end servers?

[image]